# lan1: Link is Down from time to time in OpenWrt

Tags: openwrt, lan, access-point

I have two identical Redmi AC2100 routers with OpenWrt on them. Devices is configured as "dumb" access points, connected to network with LAN interface.

One device is having the following sequence in logs:

```
Sat Jul 23 12:02:22 2022 kern.info kernel: [  633.232674] mt7530 mdio-bus:1f lan1: Link is Down
Sat Jul 23 12:02:22 2022 kern.info kernel: [  633.237793] br-lan: port 1(lan1) entered disabled state
Sat Jul 23 12:02:22 2022 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'lan1' link is down
Sat Jul 23 12:02:37 2022 kern.info kernel: [  647.568646] mt7530 mdio-bus:1f lan1: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
Sat Jul 23 12:02:37 2022 kern.info kernel: [  647.576367] br-lan: port 1(lan1) entered blocking state
Sat Jul 23 12:02:37 2022 kern.info kernel: [  647.581618] br-lan: port 1(lan1) entered forwarding state
Sat Jul 23 12:02:37 2022 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'lan1' link is up
```

During this period internet is not accessible via this AP.

How to fix?

Issuing command

```
ethtool --set-eee lan1 eee off
```

makes situation worse: lan1 goes down immediately with this command, and then is starting to go down just after each time it is up.

Comment: i have the same situation - only sometimes it comes up with 10Mbps instead of 1Gbps